# why www.prod.facebook.com opens as localhost?

Tags: facebook, localhost, subdomain

I had seen this domain name in facebook's presentation. But when I try to open. it redirect me to my localhost (WAMP).  [Open This Link](http://www.prod.facebook.com/)  of facebook's subdomain. Why It's redirecting me to my localhost.

> MY QUESTION IS HOW CAN I SET UP SERVICE LIKE THIS ON MY OWN DOMAIN ?

I had attached preview as below, if you don't have wamp / xamp installed on your machine.

[image]

** It's my localhost

Comment: It doesn't technically _redirect_ you to localhost, the hostname www.prod.facebook.com simply resolves to a localhost address (127.0.0.2).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson : my localhost address is not 127.0.0.2 !

Comment: All 127.x.x.x addresses are localhost on Windows. It's only that by convention, 127.0.0.1 is usually used (and I think MacOS only uses that single address) Try pinging any 127.x.x.x address and you'll get a reply.

Comment: +1 for '127.x.x.x' this.. :) thanks..

Answer (score 2):

All they've done is mapped (via DNS) the hostname www.prod.facebook.com to the IP address 127.0.0.2.  If you have control over your domain's DNS you can do that easily.  I'm sure they did this so that the URL looked more official in the demo, rather than putting "localhost" in the browser's URL bar.

Comment: which function i have to configure in my dns zone editor ? (on server) and can i setup this service by configuring my http.conf file of apache server ?

Comment: In DNS terms, this is an A record in a zone file.  Apache http.conf won't be involved except to set up a virtual host for whatever name you want to use for your site.  But to be clear, these are 2 separate things: DNS translates the host name into an IP address, and the machine with that IP address inspects the host name to determine what apache site to serve if you use virtual hosts.